# Как прочитать большой файл в QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt5

Не читается большой файл в QByteArray (182111787 byte):

```
QByteArray arrfile = file.readAll();
```

Размер QByteArray получается 0. Пробовал так:

```
QFile file(puth);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) { qDebug() <<"Error open file";}
    int len = file.size();
    char buf[len]; //тут выскакивает ошибка возмжно лимит массива
    QByteArray arr;
    if(file.size()>8012) {
        while (!file.atEnd()) {
            int bl = file.read(buf, 8012);
            //QByteArray qb= QByteArray::fromRawData(buf, sizeof(buf));
            //arr.append(qb);
        }
    } else {
        arr = file.readAll();
    }
    arr= QByteArray::fromRawData(buf, sizeof(buf));
    qDebug() <<"prostofile=" <<file.size() <<"qb=" <<arr.size();
    file.close();
```

При присвоении массива (char buf[len]) выскакивает ошибка, наверное есть какой нибудь лимит массива, видимо с QByteArray похожая проблема. 
Что можно с этим сделать? Мне этот файл надо передать через  QTcpSocket вот так

```
pClientSocket->write(arrBlock);
```

Но походу такое не катит. Что теперь сделать, неужели передавать куски QByteArray этого файла, вызывая  pClientSocket->flush(). Может я что то упустил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот такой конструкцией

```
char buf[len];
```

Вы выделяете память на стеке (о том, что это VLA, и будет работать только с gcc, я умолчу). Выделить на стеке больше 1 мегабайта задача еще та, обычно так просто нельзя (под линуксом это точно). Но потом все равно туда больше 8012 байт не читаете. (кстати, 0 и 9 попутали?).

Если этот файл нужно передать через сокет, то так и сделайте - читайте по 4-8 кб и отправляйте в сокет - не нужно пытаться вычитать весь файл, где то так:

```
while (1) {
   QByteArray b = file.read(8*1024);
   if (b.isEmpty()) break;
   socket.write(b);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А скажите после socket.write(b) сразу надо socket.flush() вызывать или можно потом когда все запишиться? "кстати, 0 и 9 попутали?"  Не понял если честно вопрос

Comment: по поводу 0 и 9. Вы читаете блоками по 8012. Это достаточно странный размер. Скорее всего там должно быть 8192 (что равно 8*1024). 

Делать ли flush? Это интересный вопрос. Я бы не делал. А вот проверку того, что возвращает write -  я бы добавил.

Comment: "по поводу 0 и 9. " Да я ошибся. + у меня еще ошибка я открывал файл для чтения и записи QIODevice::ReadWrite а надо QIODevice::ReadOnly, похоже из-за этого медиафайлы вылетали с ошибкой. Да теперь все надо переписывать, но вроде бы работает, насчет проверки учту, еще раз спс